difference in setInterval() speed on different browsers
let scramble = document.getElementById('scramble');
let timer = document.getElementById('timer');
const possibleMoves = ["R", "R'", "R2", "L", "L'", "L2", "U", "U'", "U2", "D", "D'", "D2", "F", "F'", "F2", "B", "B'", "B2"];
let newScramble = [];
let prevMove = '';
let prevBeforeMove = '';
let firstElOfPrevMove = '';
let firstElOfPrevBeforeMove = '';
const invalidPairs = [['R', 'L', 'R'], ['L', 'R', 'L'], ['F', 'B', 'F'], ['B', 'F', 'B'],
                      ['D', 'U', 'D'], ['U', 'D', 'U']];

function setScramble() {
    newScramble = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
        prevMove = newScramble[i - 1];
        prevBeforeMove = newScramble[i - 2];
        prevMove && prevMove.length > 0 ? firstElOfPrevMove = prevMove[0] : null;
        prevBeforeMove && prevBeforeMove.length > 0 ? firstElOfPrevBeforeMove = prevBeforeMove[0] : null;
        do {
            randomMove = possibleMoves[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleMoves.length)];
        } while (randomMove[0] === firstElOfPrevMove ||
                 invalidPairs.some(pair => pair[0] === randomMove[0] && pair[1] === firstElOfPrevMove && pair[2] === firstElOfPrevBeforeMove));
        newScramble.push(randomMove);
        scramble.textContent = newScramble.join(' ');
    }
}

//---------------------TIMER--------------------

let hours = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let seconds = 0;
let milliseconds = 0;
let isStarted = false;
let interval;

function handleInterval(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}

function startTimer(event) {
    if(event.code === 'Space' && !isStarted) {
        milliseconds = 0;
        seconds = 0;
        minutes = 0;
        isStarted = true;
        interval = setInterval(() => {
            milliseconds += 1;
            if (minutes !== 0) {
                timer.textContent = handleInterval(minutes) + ':' + handleInterval(seconds) + '.' + handleInterval(milliseconds);
            } else {
                timer.textContent = seconds + '.' + handleInterval(milliseconds);
            }
           if(milliseconds >= 99) {
                seconds++;
                milliseconds = 0;
           } 
           if(seconds >= 60) {
                seconds = 0;
                minutes++;
           }
        }, 10);
    } else {
        isStarted = false;
    }
}

 function stopTimer(event) {
    if(milliseconds >= 1 && event.code === 'Space' && isStarted) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            setScramble();
    }
 }

document.addEventListener('keyup', startTimer);
document.addEventListener('keydown', stopTimer);

setScramble();

Okay so I have a quick question. I made a website that times your rubiks cube solves and gives you a scramble (something like cstimer.net). But when I started to compare the time on my website with normal stopwatch I noticed that on firefox my time was like 1.5x slower. Then I tried the same thing on Microsoft Edge and it was working just fine.
So my question is: Why does that happen and what's the best way to fix the problem?
I assume I won't achieve my goal with setInterval + I want the website to work on all browsers (obviously).

Is it any better if you increase the interval time? It may simply not be able to keep up with running every 10 ms.

You cannot trust setInterval to run the callback exactly after the given delay has elapsed. It might execute a little -- or even a lot -- later. For that reason it is best to not do milliseconds+=1, but instead read the current time, and subtract the starting time from it. Then you have a reliable number of milliseconds.

this question is absurd. ! -> If there are performance differences depending on types of JS operations and between browser "brands", yes, of course; but this will in no way guarantee that any of them will have consistency in their execution time of the same problem.

The only way to get a true reference time is to assign a fixed time value for each movement type.

The linked Q/A answers the "why", for the best solution, you don't want the interval to dictate how long actually elapsed, for this you use the clock that's available to your script: Date.now(). Then for rendering, you use a slightly smaller interval than the precision of your rendered timer, but if it's lower than the monitor refresh rate, then use requestAnimationFrame.

@MisterJojo: What are you even talking about?
